# Does this differential equation have a solution that has certain properties?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, fixed-point-theorems

**Conjecture:** Suppose we have a function $f(x)$ and some real number $\alpha$ such that $f(\alpha)=\alpha$ and $f'(\alpha)<1$. Then there exists a solution $y(t)$ to the differential equation $f(y)-y=y'$ such that $\lim_{t\to\infty}y(t)=\alpha$.

I've tested some functions and the conjecture always seems to hold:

For $f(x)=x^2, \alpha=0$ and the corresponding solution is $\dfrac{1}{ce^t+1}$, which goes to $\alpha=0$.

If $f(x)=\sin(x)+x, \alpha = (2k+1)\pi$, then $y(t)=2\cot^{-1}(ce^{-t})+2k\pi\to(2k+1)\pi$ and so on...

I would appreciate any kind of help, discussion or source for further reading. Thanks!

Comment: Really cool question. +1 from me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conjecture is obviously correct, as $y(t)=\alpha$ satisfies the ODE. What you probably wanted to conjecture is that the steady state at $y=\alpha$ is locally attractive. The easiest to do this is by showing that it is locally exponentially stable by linearizing the ODE around $y=\alpha$:

$\frac{d}{dt}z=(-1+f'(\alpha))z+O(z^2)$,

with $z=y-\alpha$. Since $f'(\alpha)<1$, the only pole of the system, $(-1+f'(\alpha))$, is negative, the steady state thus locally exponential stable, and thus it is also locally attractive.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my statement. There indeed always exists trivial solution $y(t)=\alpha$. However, if we want to linearize the ODE we assume that $y$ eventually approaches $\alpha$, which is basically what we want to prove. Or am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: No, not really, you can always linearize an ODE given the usual assumptions about differentiablity and so. Arguably one of the main reasons to linearize is Lyapunovs direct method. It essentially states that if the linearized system is $x'=A x$ and all eigenvalues of A have negative real part, the _original_ system is locally exponentially stable. Exponential stability is way stronger than your claim. It essentially states that we can upper bound the speed of convergence to the steady state by some exponentially decreasing function. What you ask for is local attractivity, which is way weaker.